# Pre-trained models(Spacy, NLTK etc. ) for Name, Entity, Product, Place recognition for short descriptions

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, spacy

I have very short descriptions of not exceeding 40 characters. I'm using Spacy's NER model to identify Name, Entity, Products and foods.
The problem with the text descriptions I have are very short and are not proper English sentences. Spacy fails to identify Name, Entity, Products and foods and returns nulls.

For example, the first description in my table is "Monster Ultra Strawberry". But when I try to get the entity type tags for individual tokens the spacy model returns a null.

My code is as below.

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_lg')

    docs = nlp(data['desc'][0])
    for token in docs:
        print(token.ent_type_)
```

Please let me know what other models I can use in this situation? Are there model classifiers that  classify a word into these buckets - Name, Org, Food, Product etc. without additional context?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the list of entities that spaCy en_core_web_lg supports here: https://spacy.io/models/en, I do not see name, entity or food on the list.  You can further train any of the spaCy models to recognise specific entities you are looking for.

You can also create lists of keywords related to the entities you want to identify, and then use string-matching techniques to identify these keywords since there is no contextual information in your sentences. While this is not as sophisticated as NER, it can work well if you have a limited vocabulary.